# How to apply html <strong> attribute to a link made by CakePHP html helper

Tags: html, css, cakephp

How can I make the text of a link label bold in CakePHP.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
 <?php echo $html->link(__('Home', true), array('action' => 'index', 'customer_id' => $customer_id)); ?>
```

I expect the text 'Home' to appear : **Home**

The above piece of code is written in CakePHP 1.2 and was written using Cake's $html helper class.
How can I apply CSS to such codes?

I thought of using `<strong>` but I wonder is there any better option?

Comment: what is the output of the above code?

Comment: It's just a link and it will redirect to a different page. I just want this text 'Home' to be bold, using the <strong> attribute of standard html. Or is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

> I thought of using strong but I wonder is there any better option?

Yes, there is: Simply use CSS and give the link (or the parent element) a class.

```
$this->Html->link('Foo', array(/*...*/), array('class' => 'bold'));
```

The HTML element strong is, as any other element, meant to be used in [a semantic context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics). **Don't** abuse elements for visual representation! The meaning of strong is a strong expression, pronunciation and used by screen readers, braile devices and tools that analyze the semantics of markup (like bots from search engines). Even between bold and strong there is a difference in their meaning.

If you insist on using an element, well, then use `<a><span class="bold">Link</span></a>` something like this.

> The HTML span element is an inline element that can be used as a
>   container for text. The  element has no special meaning. It has
>   no required attributes, but style and class are common. Unlike ,
>   which is formatted with line breaks, the  element does not have
>   any automatic formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->tag('strong',$this->Html->link(__('Home', true), array('action' => 'index', 'customer_id' => $customer_id)), array('class' => 'welcome'));
?>
```

for V1.2

```
<?php
    echo $html->tag('strong',$html->link(__('Home', true), array('action' => 'index', 'customer_id' => $customer_id)), array('class' => 'welcome'));
    ?>
```